# How to safely & remove this associated entity, or set the ID null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

[Using Symfony2 & Doctrine]

I have two classes

```
/* AppBundle\Entity\AccessToken

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User)
     */
    protected $user;
```

and `AppBundle\Entity\User`, which contains no references to `AppBundle\Entity\AccessToken`. I get the famous parent conflict error from symfony attempting to delete a persisted User object.

Is there a way I can easily remove these access tokens, or set the user_id NULL without manually looping through my entities?

On a bidirectional association I can use cascade. I can't figure out what to do here.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set on delete parameter on your association.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
protected $user;
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I'll accept when the timer runs out